# Load interstitial ads in another activity

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm using the basic example to add ads interstitial ads in my app with admob and firebase:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
Button mNewGameButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNewGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            beginPlayingGame();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();

    mNewGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                beginPlayingGame();
            }
        }
    });

    beginPlayingGame();
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
              .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private void beginPlayingGame() {
    // Play for a while, then display the New Game Button
}
}
```

Now, I have two activities (A and B) . I want when Activity A is open, load the ads, and when Activity B is open, show the same ads loaded in A, Please help me and sorry for my bad English! I ask in this language because the English community is more effective

Comment: best practise is to create another mInterstitialAd in Activity B

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok for me. The ad is displayed after buttton click, if its loaded. So in case you start B activity in beginPlayingGame all will be ok. Fact that ad is started from A activity not B is detail.

Did you want somethink else?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible.

You have to store interstitial instance somewhere outside the Activity class (e.g. in Application class static variable) and implement listener outside this Activity.

That's it!